# angular share data between controllers and do something with that data and show it in page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I watched this:

http://www.thinkster.io/pick/9jfpSmbx1j/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

and now trying to adjust the code so I could understand more.

So here is what I made:

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
   <div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data2.length">
    <h1>{{ data2.message }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and main.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);



myApp.factory('Data', function () {
  return { message: "I'm data from a service" };
});


/*
This Data service can be injected into each of the controllers as a parameter.
By doing this, we are now attaching the data.model to an app service, which repairs 
the binding between the two controller models.
*/

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data) {
    console.log(Data.message.length);
    console.log(Data);
    $scope.data = Data;

    this.getLength = function() {
        console.log('called');
        return $scope.data.message.length;
    }

    var data2 = Data;
    data2.length = this.getLength();

    $scope.data2 = data2;
    //$scope.data.length = Data.message.length;
//  $scope.data.message = 'a';


}
```

And from logs I see that this.getLength is called only once. Why it is not called everytime the data changes? I want to update string lenght in html on every string update update.

**Update**

Fixed:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data', function () {
  return { message: "I'm data from a service" };
});


/*
This Data service can be injected into each of the controllers as a parameter.
By doing this, we are now attaching the data.model to an app service, which repairs 
the binding between the two controller models.
*/

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data) {

    $scope.data = Data;

    $scope.getLength = function() {

      return $scope.data.message.length;
    }

    var data2 = Data;

    $scope.data2 = data2;

    data2.length = $scope.getLength();

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $scope.data.message;
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue == oldValue)return; // do nothing if old value equals to old one

        data2.length = $scope.getLength();

        /****/
    }, true); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.message` model refers to `input`. Generally when you type something in input field what really changes is `data.message`. But if you want to fire other logic on change use `$watch`. (See DOCS [HERE](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope))

So add to your code:

```
  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.data.message;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue == oldValue)return; // do nothing if old value equals to old one

    this.getLength(); // I would use $scope.getLength();
    /****/
}, true);
```

Comment: With this.getLength() I did not even made it to work, but fixed with $scope.getLenght. THanks :)